# set iOS Voice Over on top of page on cordova state change

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, voiceover

I experienced that iOS voice Over does not move to the top element when a state change occurs on cordova using angular.

Android talkback does this behaviour, as it is the expected for Voice Over users.

I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

To move focus arround you want to use accessibility notifications:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, elementToFocus);
```

You just have to create a corodova plugin that gives you access to this native API.